# Any significant use of registering only Service in windsor container?

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container, registration

```
    container.Register(
    Component.For<IMyService>()
);
```

This code intent to register a service IMyService in Windsor container,but i didn't found any significance use of doing that. am i am missing something here or it is just a syntax practicing?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

In this case, since your service is an interface it's most likely not terribly useful with default configuration, because you won't be able to instantiate that component most likely.
I'm saying most likely, because you didn't show the definition of the interface, nor the code that configures your container (more on that in a moment).

If your service was a class, it would be a usable registration.

Now the more advanced stuff. In advanced scenarios you can have extensions augmenting your registration, by using custom `IContributeComponentModelConstruction`, or component model attributes (like `InterceptorAttribute`) which could extend this simple registration to something more complete.